# Unable to get table column constraint in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to create a T-SQL script to update the column datatype but the default constraints do not allow it so I have to first remove the constraints and then alter the column.

I have tried to pass the table column constraint but it does not work.

```
SELECT 
    obj_table.NAME AS 'table',
    columns.NAME AS 'column',
    obj_Constraint.NAME AS 'constraint',
    obj_Constraint.type AS 'type'
FROM 
    sys.objects obj_table
JOIN 
    sys.objects obj_Constraint ON obj_table.object_id = obj_Constraint.parent_object_id
JOIN 
    sys.sysconstraints constraints ON constraints.constid = obj_Constraint.object_id
JOIN 
    sys.columns columns ON columns.object_id = obj_table.object_id
                        AND columns.column_id = constraints.colid
                        AND columns.NAME = 'trans_reject_id'
WHERE 
    obj_table.NAME = 'abc_transaction_table'
ORDER BY 
    'table'


ALTER TABLE abc_transaction_table 
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF__abc_trans__ach_r__575DE8F7
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. Some methods of using single quotes for Aliases are deprecated and only works when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'table'` would *not* order by your column aliased as `'table'`, it would order by the `varchar` literal `'table'` (so would effectively not order at all). Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Alter column constraint you need to write your query in this way:

```
DECLARE @CONSTRAINT AS VARCHAR(255)
 SET @CONSTRAINT = (SELECT obj_Constraint.NAME AS 'constraint'
            FROM sys.objects obj_table
            JOIN sys.objects obj_Constraint
            ON obj_table.object_id = obj_Constraint.parent_object_id
            JOIN sys.sysconstraints constraints
            ON constraints.constid = obj_Constraint.object_id
            JOIN sys.columns columns
            ON columns.object_id = obj_table.object_id
            AND columns.column_id = constraints.colid
            WHERE obj_table.NAME='abc_transaction_table'
            AND columns.Name = 'trans_reject_id'
            )
 DECLARE @REMOVE_CONSTARINT VARCHAR(255)
 SET @REMOVE_CONSTARINT = 'ALTER TABLE abc_transaction_table DROP CONSTRAINT' + @CONSTRAINT
 EXEC(@REMOVE_CONSTARINT)
```

Comment: You should wrap the injected name of `@REMOVE_CONSTARINT` in `QUOTENAME`, otherwise someone with access to create `CONSTRAINT`s might be able to elevate their permissions. Also, as it stands, you'll get a syntax error as you have no space between the keyword `CONSTRAINT` and the injected value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT dc.name constraint_name, 
       schema_name(dc.schema_id) schema_name, 
       object_name(dc.parent_object_id) table_name,
       c.name column_name
FROM sys.default_constraints dc
join sys.columns c 
  on dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
 and dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
```